# Debugging model with custom validation in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm a newbie of ASP.NET Core MVC and I'm working on a project. I tried to debug values that are returned from form and mapping those values into my model but I cannot dive into my custom validation class, specific is property `Name` in the model. So, I hope anyone can give me some advice to fix it. Have a great day and a nice weekend guys!! :D

My custom validation class:

```
public class NotNullOrWhiteSpaceValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public NotNullOrWhiteSpaceValidatorAttribute() : base("Invalid Field") { }
    public NotNullOrWhiteSpaceValidatorAttribute(string Message) : base(Message) { }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString())) 
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (IsValid(value)) 
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        return new ValidationResult("Value cannot be empty or white space.");
    }
}
```

My model class:

```
public class AR_App
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [NotNullOrWhiteSpaceValidator]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotNullOrWhiteSpaceValidator]
    [MaxLength(5)]
    public string? LanguageCode { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(300)]
    public string? IconPath { get; set; }

    public int? Status { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string? UpdatedAction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You mean you are not able to debug the validator code?

Comment: You should use RequiredAttribute with `AllowEmptyStrings` property set to false. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks a lot Chetan. Maybe I put the wrong redpoint